# Screenshot Only Part of Screen - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, screenshot, fullscreen

I'm using this Swift code to take a screenshot of my app:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size, false, 0);
self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
var image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

How would I go about taking a screenshot of only part of the screen, and not all of it, as I do here?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For example if you want to take the screen shot of the `UIView` rectangle at position `(50,50)` with height  of `(100,150)`.

First set the Image Context to the size of the rectangle. This sets the image size.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(100,150), false, 0);
```

Now draw the view in this context in such a way that, the **visible part of the screenshot** starts at `(50,50)`

```
self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(CGRectMake(-50,-50,view.bounds.size.width,view.bounds.size.height) afterScreenUpdates: true)
```

This clips the screen shot at `(100,150)` because we set the size of our `context`. Now take the UIImage from this.

```
var image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer!

Comment: mama nuvvu keka mama ;)

Comment: Not working for me. Would you mind taking a look at my code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34887164/how-to-screenshot-just-part-of-a-screen

Comment: for swift 5 use CGRect instead of CGRectmake
ie .. CGRect(x: -50,y: -50,width: view.bounds.size.width,height: view.bounds.size.height)

Comment: Can anyone please answer why you multiply the origin by -1 for both x and y? Shouldn't it be only y-axis?

Comment: Can you explain why the negation is necessary?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best Answer to take a shot of part of the screen:

```
func screenShot() {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width*0.99,self.frame.size.height*0.70), false, 0)
    var image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    self.view?.drawViewHierarchyInRect(CGRectMake(-01, -01, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height), afterScreenUpdates: true)
    var screenShot  = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for taking a snapshot selecting by area of another UIView

```
// viewObject: UIView linked from storyboard
var bounds= CGRect(x: -viewObject.frame.minX,y: -viewObject.frame.minY,width: view.bounds.size.width,height: view.bounds.size.height)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewObject.frame.size)
        view.drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let outputImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: Can you explain why the negation is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

```
func captureView(view: UIView) -> UIImage {
    var screenRect: CGRect = view.bounds
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(screenRect.size, true, 0)
    var ctx: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    UIColor.black.set()
    ctx.fill(screenRect)
    view.layer.render(in: ctx)
    var newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```